# Aluffi: submodule $\Longleftrightarrow$ cokernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Aluffi makes the following brief statement, in the context of modules:  "The last sentence of Proposition 6.2 simply reiterates the slogan

submodule $\Longleftrightarrow$ kernel

and its mirror statement (which is just as true).  Further details are left to the reader."

By the mirror statement, does he mean that if $N' \subset N$ is a submodule, then there exists a module $M$ and an $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi \colon M \to N$ such that $N' \cong N / \text{Im}(\varphi)$?  If this is what he means, then I am having trouble proving it.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: "I am having trouble proving it" -- for good reasons, because not every submodule is isomorphic to a quotient module. I think the correct mirror slogan is "quotient module $\Longleftrightarrow$ cokernel", or, more precisely, "a quotient $R$-module of $N$ is the cokernel of some map $M \to N$, and conversely". I don't have the context, though (I didn't learn algebra from Aluffi -- maybe I should have).

Comment: Do you by chance have an example?  Btw, "The last sentence of Proposition 6.2" is "Further, every monomorphism identifies its source with the kernel of some morphism, and every epimorphism identifies its target with the cokernel of some morphism."  In my opinion, it is a more ambiguous statement than usual, for Aluffi.

Comment: An example of what? Of a submodule which is not isomorphic to a quotient module? Here is an overkill one: Let $R = \mathbb{Q}\left[x_1, x_2, x_3, ...\right]$ (polynomial ring in countably many variables). The submodule $x_1 R + x_2 R + x_3 R + ...$ of $R$ is not finitely generated and hence not $\cong$ to a quotient module of $R$.

Comment: I am just confused by this paragraph.  A monomorphism is injective, so its kernel is (usually) the farthest thing away from its source, and the same for the epimorphism case.

Comment: By "this paragraph", I meant "The last sentence of Proposition 6.2", given above.

Comment: "Some morphism" is not the monomorphism! A monomorphism $i : M \to N$ identifies its source with the kernel of the projection morphism $N \to N / i\left(M\right)$.

Comment: Ergh, I see your point.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I can see how $i: M \to N$ identifies its source with the kernel of the projection morphism $N \to N/i(M)$. But how does this iterate the slogan submodule $\iff$ kernel? Is it by restricting the monomorphism $i: M \to N$ to a submodule of $M$?

Comment: @AlJebr: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, but Aluffi is being vague here, so I am not surprised about the confusion. All I am getting out of his sentence is "every submodule is a kernel of some linear map, and conversely every kernel of some linear map is a submodule". This is *not* in any way a bijection: If you have a kernel of a linear map $f$, consider it just as a submodule while forgetting $f$, and then again construct a linear map whose kernel it is, then this new map usually will be $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the comments sufficed for me.